# How do airlines pay for aviation fuel and services at an airport they don't normally use?

Tags: airline-operations

On flights of a regular nature to set destination airports, I assume that there is a system is in place between airlines and airports/providers to pay invoices for fuel/services.

What do airlines do if diverted to an airport that the airline never normally serves or a freight airline doing a one-off flight to an airport? How do they pay? Does the captain carry a company credit card to pay for these one off charges?

Answer (score 5):

In the United States most places take credit cards.

Large carriers generally get billed, or for smaller airports they use a company credit card. There are even specialized credit cards that are designed specifically for this use.

There is also what is called "contract fuel". Basically there is a company that is a middleman, a fuel supplier who pays the airport fuel company and then rebills the airline. The pilot has a card that identifies them as a client of the fuel contractor.

For example, check out [AEG Fuels](http://aegfuels.com/), a typical fuel contractor. (Please click on that link. I get 25 cents every time you do. Just kidding.)

[image]

Comment: do they get air miles!

Comment: You've gotta check out [this article!](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2189791/Air-France-pilot-asks-passengers-chip-fuel-unscheduled-landing-Damascus.html)